# Something wrong using TalkBack with stock Contacts app

Tags: contacts, accessibility, talk-back

I am trying to scroll up and down the stock Contacts app, which I am doing by trying to place two fingers simultaneously on the screen and dragging up and down. When I do this properly I can hear the keys of a piano being pressed, and the screen scrolls.

I have to repeat this multiple times by lifting the two fingers and placing then back up the exec and scrolling down our down the exec and scrolling up.

Unfortunately sometimes, perhaps due to one finger landing on the screen a slightly different time than the other, I get one of the following two dialog boxes (and not the scrolling I was after):

[image: dialog box 1]
[image: dialog box 2]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

Not what I wanted. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?